# what is the complement of a complete graph. Does it exists or not?

Tags: graph-theory

is it possible to find a complement graph of a complete graph. I tried a lot but, am not getting it. If someone answer, it is appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) of a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) is an [edgeless graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeless_graph#Edgeless_graph) and vice versa

Comment: can we term it as isolated graph?

Comment: Isolated graph is not a term I'm familiar with, yes all the vertices are isolated vertices, but edgeless (or edge-free) graph are terms I'm familiar with.